# VsCode remove indent style - dot

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I'd like to remove/disable light grey dots.

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Just put this line in your `settings.json` file:

```
"editor.renderWhitespace": "none"
```

Another approach is via the main menu `View -> Toggle Render Whitespace`

Answer (score 15):

To remove/disable/hide VsCode gray dots, 
Go to the **View** tab and **uncheck** this: `View > Render Whitespace`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try shortcut `Ctrl+R,Ctrl+W`

Comment: Control + R is for changing workspace, where Control + W is to close tab.