# VSCode IDE messes up RTL strings after selecting

Tags: visual-studio-code, right-to-left, farsi

Recently, I had to reinstall windows 11 on my machine. So, after that, I had to install VSCode again (therefore, I have the most recent version of VSCode).

Now, whenever I select any Persian sentences (strings) in my code, the IDE shows a messed-up string that is far away from the correct one. I can not show the correct and incorrect sentences as texts here because copying and pasting results in the correct format. Therefore, I have to provide them as images. (Sorry for any inconvenience, in advance)

##### Correct Persian Sentence

[image: Correct Image]

##### Incorrect Persian Sentence (After selecting)

[image: Incorrect Image]

This might be a little bit tricky to understand for people who are not familiar with the Persian Language. The difference can be understood by looking at the first word after `$creatorId` in both images.

This also might happen if we wanted to write in Arabic or other right-to-left languages.

It would be highly appreciated if you could suggest anything to avoid this.

Comment: Mr. Kiani
I have the same problems you have. My Visual Studio code can not select rtl string correctly and the text jumps over it while selecting and the selection result is not consistent.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Dear @MahyarMajidi , Having searched extensively, I found a solution. You can find it in my answer here. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found the proper answer on one of the [VScode repository's issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146537). The problem was with the way the new version of VSCode renders the whitespace. So, to solve this problem, you need to follow the below steps:

- Open VSCode command pallete by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- Search for **Open Settings (JSON)** and click on it. It should open a JSON file named *setting*.
- In this JSON file, add a key named **editor.renderWhitespace** and assign on of the following values to it: **boundary**, **trailing** or **none**. Your JSON file should look something like this:

```
{
    "editor.renderWhitespace":"boundary"
}
```

The weird messed-up string is disapeared now.

#### Note

You can also access and change the **editor.renderWhitespace** using the settings editor. So, if you find the steps mentioned above frustrating, just use the settings editor (you can open it using the setting icon at the right end of the VSCode window or even using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) and search for **editor.renderWhitespace**. Then choose one of the three above-mentioned options.

Comment: Now the problem is gone, Thank you MR. Kiani ... well done

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton for posting this! It seems `boundary` is the most optimal value. Although now I can see dozens of dots before each line of code. Any idea on how to hide/disable that ?

Comment: @xperator Thanks for the comment. Honestly, I can not see any dots, given that I have set the `renderWhitespace` on the `boundary`. Can you elaborate on what is going on in the line you mentioned? Maybe I could help. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... It's weird how your vscode does not show them, maybe it's your theme. If you google "vscode how to hide dots" you can see results which lead to the same setting we're talking about here ( ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668506/vscode-remove-indent-style-dot ). Either way I found a workaround by just changing it's color to transparent using `editorWhitespace.foreground`

Comment: Fixes for both https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146537 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99589 were released with April recovery 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22March+2022+Recovery%22+is%3Aclosed